# how to write a shell script that copies an entire subdirectory structure as the structure of another subdirectory?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts

Write a shell script that copies an entire subdirectory structure as the structure of another subdirectory. The two subdirectories are read as arguments from the command line.Please guys i really need your help .

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073969/copy-folder-structure-without-files-from-one-location-to-another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy directory structure with [cpio](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/cpio.1.html):

```
$ find -depth -type d -print0 | cpio -0 -pvdm ../target
```

Or

```
$ find source -depth -type d \
  -printf %P\\0 | cpio -0 -pvdm -D source target
```

script.sh:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

[[ $# != 2 ]] \
      && exit 1

[[ ! -d $1 || ! -d $2 ]] && exit 1

find "$1" -depth -type d \
  -printf %P\\0 | cpio -0 -pvdm -D "$1" "${2%%+(/)}"
```

```
$ ./script.sh source/ target/
```

Comment: and how do i select the two directories from keyboard i mean like echo enter the first directory smth like this

Comment: i tried this but i don t konow if it s correct

Comment: echo "Enter the directory to be modified:"
       read orgdir 
 echo "Enter target directory:"
           read target 
           mkdir $target 
           cp $orgdir $target
fi

Comment: i tried your script it says you must chose one cpio option